# Using alias when joining three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use an alias for the following SQL query in SQL Server:

```
      a.client_id, a.name, b.address_line_1, a.address_id, a.contact_id
    , b.address_id, c.email, c.mobile_number, c.telephone_number, c.contact_id
    , c.contact_first_name 
 from client a, address b, contact c 
where a.address_id = b.address_id and a.contact_id = c.contact_id
```

I tried this but am getting an exception

```
SELECT a.client_id AS a.ClientId
    ,a.NAME AS a.NAME
    ,a.address_id AS a AddressId
    ,a.contact_id AS a.ContactId
    ,b.address_line_1 AS b.AddressLine1
    ,b.address_id AS b.AddressId
    ,c.email AS c.Email
    ,c.mobile_number AS c.MobileNumber
    ,c.telephone_number AS c.TelephoneNumber
    ,c.contact_id AS c.ContactId
    ,c.contact_first_name AS c.ContactFirstName
FROM client a
    ,address b
    ,contact c
WHERE a.address_id AS a.AddressId = b.address_id AS b.AddressId
    AND a.contact_id AS a.ClientId = c.contact_id AS c.ClientId
```

Comment: Are you going to be kind enough to tell anyone what exception you're getting?

Comment: .. and what is your DBMS?

Comment: Don't put a dot in an alias; and don't put an AS in a where clause.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Also: I would recommend using **meaningful** aliases - not just `a, b, c` for your tables. Use `a` for the `Address`, `cl` for the `Client` and `co` for `Contact` or something like this - something that's easily recognizable

Answer (score 3):

There are a few small errors in your statement.  The column aliases shouldn't be prefixed with `a.`,`b.`,`c.` and you don't put aliases in the `WHERE` clause.  It's also better to join tables together using `JOIN` statements rather them bringing them all in and using a `WHERE` clause to filter them. See the below for an example of what should work for you:

```
SELECT
     a.client_id AS ClientId
    ,a.NAME AS NAME
    ,a.address_id AS AddressId
    ,a.contact_id AS ContactId
    ,b.address_line_1 AS AddressLine1
    ,c.email AS Email
    ,c.mobile_number AS MobileNumber
    ,c.telephone_number AS TelephoneNumber
    ,c.contact_first_name AS ContactFirstName
FROM
    client AS a
    INNER JOIN address AS b
        ON (a.address_id = b.address_id)
    INNER JOIN contact AS c
        ON (a.contact_id = c.contact_id)
;
```

Comment: I think it's `a.address_id = b.address_id` and also `a.contact_id = c.contact_id`.

Comment: @DavidWallace spotted that myself as well just after I posted it, I've corrected it in the answer now :)

Comment: You've also got some duplicated column aliases in the SELECT part.

Comment: Opps, fixed that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While creating aliases you can't use the `.` since it will give you syntax error. Better specify aliases like `a.ClientId as aClientID, c.ClientId as cClientID`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an alias on `where` statementent as you did

```
where a.somefield AS whatever = ...
                   ^ this is wrong
```

You can't use an alias with an alias like you did:

```
select a.client_id as a.client_id
                      ^ here
```

The `a.` is already the alias for your table, so you just name the field as you like. You should do as this:

```
select a.client_id as FieldClientId
```